# How to make PApplet doesn't show a window

Tags: java, processing

I think this is so wrong, but I need it...

So, to run Processing's sketch in *Java mode*, you have to `extends PApplet` in the main class, and there, in the `setup()` determine the window size using `size(int x, int y)`. Then when you run it, it'll show a Java window Applet Viewer.

What I wanna ask is, how to prevent that window from appearing? I've tried to remove the `size` method, but it appeared in (what seems like) it's default size. Tried put 0 as params, went wrong (the x and y have to be > 0).

Is there any way to do that?

If there's any lack information or I've made a mistake with the post, please tell me.

## 1st edit - add more info

Let's say I have 2 classes: the one that implemented Processing and extends PApplet is named `Pikachu` by me, and an ordinary Java class I named `Jojo`. Jojo will pass params to Pikachu and Pikachu will process that param. The param is `image's name`, or if it could, an image itself (I don't know yet tho, can Processing execute Image class from Java?). Then Processing will process that image, gave an output, again as image (Yet, again I don't know yet, can Processing gave output an image for Java to use?). So, that's why I don't need a window to appear.

Comment: Why do you want to hide the window? What parts of Processing are you trying to use?

If you have Processing on your classpath, you don't *have* to extend PApplet to use any of the other Processing classes.

Comment: So I'm searching for a library that fits my needs, and found it in a form of Processing. I'm sorry, I'm newbie in all of this, but what do you mean by "If you have Processing on your classpath, you don't have to extend PApplet"?

Comment: What part of Processing are you trying to use, if you don't want the PApplet to be visible? Processing is an entire API. Extending PApplet is probably the most common thing people use it for, but it's not the only way to use it.

Comment: Aaah I see... I wanna use it in Java Mode, in Eclipse. I was just following the tutorial in Processing site (http://processing.org/tutorials/eclipse/) I thought that you have to ALWAYS extend that if you want to use it as Java?

Comment: What part of Processing are you trying to use, if you don't want the PApplet to be visible?

Comment: I'm sorry, but before I make a wild guess or answer randomly, what exactly do you mean by "part of Processing"?

Comment: Processing is an entire API. You say that part of that API suits one of your needs, but you don't want the visible PApplet part of Processing. That's certainly doable, but you have to tell me which part of Processing you're trying to use before I can help you. What exactly are you trying to do? What is your end goal?

Comment: Aaa... sorry... I wanna use Blobscanner (https://sites.google.com/site/blobscanner/blog). There, I'll load image using `PImage`, and process something out of it. I DO need the image output, but I don't wanna show it in Applet Window, and don't want it to appear.

Comment: If Processing is on your classpath, then you can simply use PImage. You only have to extend PApplet if you want to show a PApplet. The tutorials all show that case because it's the most common one. You know Java has its own image classes without requiring Processing though, right?

Comment: @KevinWorkman Sir, I really am so moved you care that much and so patient with my stupidity T_T... So many good people here... I've edited it, is that what you ask? Is the name of the class is `Image`? I accept the image as an array of byte[]...

Comment: The questions you're asking don't really make much sense. What exactly is your end goal? It doesn't make sense for Processing to "own" a class named Pikachu. If all you're doing is manipulating images, you don't need Processing at all. What **specifically** are you trying to do? Why do you need Processing to do it?

Comment: Sir, thank you very much! I've edited my question once again, but someone got what I was searching for! Again, thank you so very much for your concern!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can try to use the Frame object.

In the documentation there is a function .setVisible(boolean b)
If you call .setVisible(false) you can turn the frame off.

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setVisible(boolean)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setVisible%28boolean%29)

I am not sure how to access the frame using pure Java. In processing you can simply call

frame.setVisible(false);

Hope this helps

Comment: Dude! You gave me an enlightenment... At first it gave weird behavior, but searching and searching for the setVisible you mentioned brought me to this page (http://processing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/processing/build/javadoc/core/processing/core/PApplet.html), and well finally I get an implementation that I can understand to make it visible or not! Thank you very much Siiir!

Comment: I am very glad to hear it worked for you.. 
This is my first ever answer btw.. :)